# Как правильно сконфигурировать package.json для запуска/отладки/разработки nodejs api/app с pm2 babel7 express react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babel, pm2

Как правильно сконфигурировать package.json для запуска/отладки/разработки nodejs api/app с pm2 babel7 express react?

Интересует пример реального конфиг файл, а также настройки для тестовой и продуктивной среды.

Comment: package.json не предназначен для конфигураций, он просто хранит список ваших библиотек и команды запуска скриптов

Comment: @RTW можете показать пример package.json и babel.config.json и .env  с разделением настроек для production, development, testing ?

Comment: Я использую Next.js, поэтому не могу дать точный пример. Для express запускайте сервер с командой NODE_ENV=development. Для реакта конфигурируйте вебпак https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

Comment: Если вы учитесь или у вас новый react проект, попробуйте next.js, там всё работает из коробки и не нужно мучатся с настройками.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел старые конфиги :)

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App",
  "scripts": {
    "git-push": "git add . && git commit -m . --allow-empty && git push origin master",
    "update": "npx npm-check-updates -u",
    "server-dev": "pm2 flush && pm2 start --only https-dev && pm2 logs",
    "server-dev-full": "pm2 flush && pm2 start --only http-dev && pm2 start --only https-dev && pm2 start --only jobs-dev && pm2 logs",
    "server-prod": "pm2 start --only http-prod && pm2 start --only https-prod && pm2 start --only jobs-prod",
    "react-dev": "cd frontend && webpack -w --mode development",
    "react-prod": "cd frontend && webpack --mode production",
    "react-analyze": "cd frontend && webpack --mode production --analyze true"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@tippy.js/react": "^2.2.2",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.4",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "dompurify": "^1.0.11",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "fastify": "^2.6.0",
    "fastify-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "fastify-rate-limit": "^2.1.1",
    "fastify-static": "^2.5.0",
    "ioredis": "^4.10.0",
    "marked": "^0.6.3",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "pino": "^5.12.6",
    "pino-pretty": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "tippy.js": "^4.3.4",
    "use-debounce": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-ssh": "^6.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
  }
}
```

ecosystem.config.js:

```
const shared = {
  merge_logs: true,
  out_file: '~/.pm2/logs/combined.log',
  error_file: '~/.pm2/logs/combined.log'
}

const appsDev = {
  watch: ['backend', 'global', 'private'],
  ignore_watch: ['node_modules'],
  watch_options: {
    followSymlinks: false
  },
  autorestart: false
}

const appsProd = {
  autorestart: true,
  max_memory_restart: '400M',
  min_uptime: 20000, // 20s
  restart_delay: 10000, // 10s
  max_restarts: 10 // Number of times a script is restarted when it exits in less than min_uptime
}

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    // Jobs планировщик
    {
      name: 'jobs-dev',
      script: './backend/esm-jobs.js',
      ...appsDev,
      ...shared
    },
    {
      name: 'jobs-prod',
      script: './backend/esm-jobs.js',
      ...appsProd,
      ...shared
    },
    // HTTP
    {
      name: 'http-dev',
      script: './backend/esm-http.js',
      ...appsDev,
      ...shared
    },
    {
      name: 'http-prod',
      script: './backend/esm-http.js',
      ...appsProd,
      ...shared
    },
    // HTTPS
    {
      name: 'https-dev',
      script: './backend/esm-https.js',
      ...appsDev,
      ...shared
    },
    {
      name: 'https-prod',
      script: './backend/esm-https.js',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
      ...appsProd,
      ...shared
    }
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'),
  path = require('path'),
  BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  let isProd = argv.mode == 'production'

  let config = {
    entry: './client.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve('../public'),
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        frontend: path.resolve('./index'),
        global: path.resolve('../global/index'),
        backend: path.resolve('../backend/index'),
        public: path.resolve('../public')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      argv.analyze ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : false,
      isProd ? new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin() : false,
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /ru/)
    ].filter(Boolean),
    optimization: {
      minimize: isProd ? true : false
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false
    }
  }

  return config
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not ie 11", "not op_mini all"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: Несколько вопросов.  Почему не использовали - babel.config.json? Почему не использовали .env? Почему babel в продакшен рефернсах, а не dev? Спасибо за инфо. Есть что проанализировать и решить как лучше сконфигурировать среды.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev .babelrc это тоже самое что babel.config.json насколько я знаю, но так как конфигурация у меня не различалась на проде/дев, то и настраивать что-то не надо было. .env не использовал так как не знал о нём и обходился просто приватным файлом не передающимся через git, но вполне удобное решение для хранения всяких паролей к базе данных и прочему. Почему babel в продакшен рефернсах, а не dev? - да это не важно абсолютно, не влияет ни на что :) Раньше придерживался мнения, что всё что используется в коде - это не Дев.